# Communicating with user servers under App Transport Security

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I am currently developing an application that requires connecting to user provided and possibly also user hosted services. These services don't all support HTTPS. In the past `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` would have enabled the user to connect to those services despite App Transport Security. As I understand, `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` will be deprecated soon without any direct replacement.

I have two questions about App Transport Security:

- When will `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` be deprecated?
- How do I connect to those services afterwards or will that not be possible?

Along that line, my app should also support untrusted TLS certificates. At the moment, I plan on implementing that in `urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)` of URLSessionTaskDelegate.

Is that a valid and allowed way of handling this situation?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` will not be deprecated. You can still use it. But from January 2017 on, there will be a new restriction: Apps that have ATS exceptions defined in their `info.plist` won't be approved anymore, when you don't have a good reason. (this is for new builds only. Any build that is live on the AppStore at the moment won't be affected.)

See [Session 706](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/706/) of the WWDC 2016 for more information. [This thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48979) in the Developer Forums may contain some useful information for you, too.

---

Using `URLSession` will still work. You don't have to change any of your code. But without the ATS exception, you need trusted TLS certificates.